# Where can I download Enterprise architect 8.0 from?

Tags: download, enterprise-architect

In school we use this software to create UML diagrams. We have to do some homeworks, but in school we use version 8.0. Is here someone who knows where I can get this version of EA (because we get licence key for this version from teacher). I'm searching two days already.

Comment: If you have a license to use at your school's computers, I'm *pretty* sure you can't use the same license at home. Have you asked your teacher yet whether they can supply you with a proper license or installation?

Comment: he gave us the licence by his own, so i think its ok

Comment: If he gave you the license "by his own", doesn't necessarily mean it's legal.

Comment: lets forget about the license, i will use freeware or trial for this homework, but where can i get one?

Answer (score 0):

There are many open source and otherwise free UML tools. Such as:

- http://creately.com/
- http://www.bouml.fr/
- http://www.softwareideas.net/en/Default.aspx (free for non-commercial use)
- http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/index.html

Enterprise architect has a steep learning curve and is overkill for most things. There is, however, a trial download - I found it at:

http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/downloads.html

Comment: thx, but i need EA because i need to open eap file that i created in school, and if i install trial that you suggest, its expired immediatelly after installation

Comment: Hmm, annoying. I'd suggest emailing or otherwise contacting Sparx to see if you can get a new trial version. It may be that you had the trial installed previously and it has now timed out? Systems like this tend to hide the details somewhere in the registry or a hidden file.